# How to select non-NA values for each ID if present otherwise select NA in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, case

I have a df which can have single/several rows per ID. If it has multiple rows, only 1 row is populated with a non-NA value for a column. Sometimes all rows are NA. Using Oracle, I want to query out non-NA values if they exist otherwise the NA values as it is.

```
df:
ID Category  
1  NA  
1  A  
1  NA  
2  B  
2  NA  
3  NA  
4  C
```

I want to have the following as the final result df.

```
df:
ID  Category  
1  A  
2  B  
3  NA  
4  C
```

I tried joining with where clause non-NA but that is omiting ID 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are not any nulls in the column category, for this sample data,  you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
  coalesce(max(case when category <> 'NA' then category end), 'NA') category
from tablename
group by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=84973cded04ac6d607a0ded0f35ee403).